# Accessing ServiceSecurityContext.Current.PrimaryIdentity.Name from within a WCF service

Tags: wcf

I'm very new to WCF, but I've searched this topic pretty thoroughly and haven't come up with a satisfactory answer, so here goes my question:

While within my WCF service, I need to access the user's username.  From everything I've read, I should be able to get that from ServiceSecurityContext.Current.PrimaryIdentity.Name.  However, instead of returning Domain\Username as I had hoped, it always returns NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE . How can I get the actual Domain and Username of the individual that is logged in to the machine accessing my service?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the [ServiceSecurityContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicesecuritycontext.aspx) Class?

> Represents the security context of a remote party. On the client,
>   represents the service identity and, on the service, represents the
>   client identity.

e.g.

```
ServiceSecurityContext.Current.WindowsIdentity.Name
```

...ensuring that you have your service set up to authenticate via Windows security.

Answer (score 0):

To Use Windows credentials , set the clientCredentialType to "Windows". use wsHttpBinding, or  netTcpBinding if its within LAN

```
    <bindings>
  <netTcpBinding>
    <binding name="WindowsCredentials">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </netTcpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Comment: Lingaraj - Tried as you suggested with both wsHttpBinding and netTcpBinding.  Either way, I'm still getting NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE when I look at either ServiceSecurityContext.Current.PrimaryIdentity.Name or ServiceSecurityContext.Current.WindowsIdentity.Name.  For clarification, what I'm trying to do is to allow everyone access to my WCF service, and then once a user is in the service, find out whether the user is authenticated (Windows Auth) and return the groups that the user belongs to.  For this, I need access to the user's actual domain and username.